# How to control whether a space is printed?

Tags: c++

I am unable to interpret the meaning of the following code. Could someone please shed some light on it. In the following code, the bool variable firstword controls the printing of a space. However, since it is true, the if statement in the second while loop will never go to the else statement to print the space. Is my interpretation right or am I reading it wrong? Thanks

```
void word_transform(ifstream &map_file, ifstream &input)
{
  auto trans_map = buildMap(map_file); // store the transformations
  string text;
  while(getline(input,text)){
      istringstream stream(text);
      string word;
      bool firstword = true;
      while(stream>>word){
         if(firstword)
             firstword = false;
         else
             cout<<" ";
      }
      cout<<endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, what happens when firstword is true ? It's set to false. So then what happens the next iteration of the inner loop  ?

Comment: I feels like it's missing a `cout << word;` between the `cout<<" ";` and the closing brace ... otherwise it's just printing spaces, not space-separated words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 bool firstword = true;
      while(stream>>word){
         if(firstword)
             firstword = false; // <<<<<<<<<<
         else
             cout<<" ";
     }
```

First iteration: `firstword is true;` set firstwort to false

2nd iteration: `firstword is false;` else-statement executed